# MailChimp: Sending mergetags to campaign over API

Tags: php, mailchimp

I'm using the MailChimp PHP API and oAuth2 to connect to MailChimp and create a campaign. Everything is peachy except for my mergetags that I have to put inside an . For example,

```
<a href="*|FORWARD|*">forward</a>
```

becomes

```
<a href="/*|FORWARD|*">forward</a>
```

when it gets to MailChimp.
Then, when emailed it strips the whole thing out.

```
<a>forward</a>
```

I've messed around with a few things but nothing seems to effect it. I don't know if it's me, if it's mailchimp, or what.

Comment: The campaign content comes from a Joomla component and uses file_get_contents to vomit everything up. There isn't any funky htmlentities or anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by not putting the mergetag inside a quote

```
<a href=*|forward|*>Forward</a>
```